# Where is client-dependencies-gradle exposing depedencies?

Tags: gradle, polymer

I am using [client-dependencies-gradle](https://github.com/craigburke/client-dependencies-gradle) plugin (to install polymer).

```
clientDependencies {
    bower {
        'jquery'('2.0.0')
    }
    npm {
        "@polymer/paper-checkbox"("^3.0.0-pre.12")
        "@polymer/polymer"("^3.0.0-pre.12")
        "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs"("^1.2.0")
    }
}
```

I see that the depedencies are installed (i.e. the diretory build/client-cache/npm/@polymer/ is populated).

I do not find documentation about how client depedencies are acccesed from client application.

For example,

curl localhost:8080/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/b6e46ee59e51fe258423440aa58327d5/webcomponents-lite.js

curl localhost:8080/jquery/jquery.js

Where is the client supposed to see these files?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to modify the configuration of spring static content location. I did it by adding the following line to `application.properties`. The default is:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/
```

I just appended `classpath:/vendor/` to make spring look for static content there too.

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/,classpath:/vendor/
```

The `/src/assets/vendor` directory is mapped to the url http://localhost:8080/. For example jquery that is installed under `/usr/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js` is located at http://localhost:8080/jquery/jquery.js